# Device can ping, but not TFTP/GET from the server

Tags: networking, ssh, cloud, tftp, gns3

I am trying to set up device with GNS3 by using my company cloud site, and I am blocked by tftp service.

First of all, here are 2 Cloud Instances I have generated on this cloud site. As listed in this chart, "Basement" and "US-237". Both instance have a internal IP, **10.31.1.97** or **10.31.1.116** respectively, both have a "floating IP", **10.96.131.107** or **10.96.128.81** respectively. This Cloud Site is built somewhere in Canada, and if I was to ssh to those instance from US, which is where I am, I have to use the floating IP address to make the connection.

[image]

On this "Basement" host, I have started a tftp service which is try to provide the device license file to any incoming calls. And I have checked this tftp service is up and running OK.

On this "US-237" host side, I have created a basic gns3 project as such:

[image]

Which has the diagram of:  Cloud <--> Cisco Router <--> Switch <--> X-1, which is my device.

From the device console, I was able to ping this "Basement" with its regular ip, or its floating IP address. But If I was try to tftp file from "basement" to my device, it is totally timeout. Here is the log message on my device side:

```
 # execute ping 10.31.1.97
PING 10.31.1.97 (10.31.1.97): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.31.1.97: seq=0 ttl=62 time=13.664 ms
64 bytes from 10.31.1.97: seq=1 ttl=62 time=20.204 ms
64 bytes from 10.31.1.97: seq=2 ttl=62 time=16.804 ms

--- 10.31.1.97 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 13.664/16.890/20.204 ms

 # execute ping 10.96.131.107
PING 10.96.131.107 (10.96.131.107): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.96.131.107: seq=0 ttl=61 time=16.563 ms
64 bytes from 10.96.131.107: seq=1 ttl=61 time=13.185 ms
64 bytes from 10.96.131.107: seq=2 ttl=61 time=19.592 ms

--- 10.96.131.107 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 12.893/16.421/19.937 ms
 #
 #
 # execute bios get 10.96.131.107 FX200FTQ2109C2EL.rom
tftp: timeout
Get BIOS file failed...
 #
 # execute bios get 10.31.1.97 FX200FTQ2109C2EL.rom
tftp: timeout
Get BIOS file failed...
```

And in parallel if I was to to run tcpdump on the basement side, I have seen such messages during 10.96.131.107 tftp session:

```
18:06:12.999230 IP basement.43620 > oak.fortinet.com.domain: 50389+ [1au] PTR? 6.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.2.0.f.f.ip6.arpa. (101)
18:06:13.008726 IP oak.fortinet.com.domain > basement.43620: 50389 NXDomain 0/1/1 (165)
18:06:13.008814 IP basement.43620 > oak.fortinet.com.domain: 50389+ PTR? 6.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.2.0.f.f.ip6.arpa. (90)
18:06:13.017780 IP oak.fortinet.com.domain > basement.43620: 50389 NXDomain 0/1/0 (154)
18:06:24.459591 IP 10.96.128.81.15987 > basement.tftp:  37 RRQ "FX200FTQ2109C2EL.rom" octet tsize 0
18:06:24.460896 IP basement.47531 > 10.96.128.81.15987: UDP, length 516
18:06:24.461240 IP 10.96.128.81 > basement: ICMP 10.96.128.81 udp port 15987 unreachable, length 552
18:06:24.560211 IP 10.96.128.81.58208 > basement.tftp:  37 RRQ "FX200FTQ2109C2EL.rom" octet tsize 0
18:06:24.561319 IP basement.51987 > 10.96.128.81.58208: UDP, length 516
18:06:24.561699 IP 10.96.128.81 > basement: ICMP 10.96.128.81 udp port 58208 unreachable, length 552
18:06:24.711391 IP 10.96.128.81.35729 > basement.tftp:  37 RRQ "FX200FTQ2109C2EL.rom" octet tsize 0
18:06:24.712479 IP basement.55350 > 10.96.128.81.35729: UDP, length 516
18:06:24.712903 IP 10.96.128.81 > basement: ICMP 10.96.128.81 udp port 35729 unreachable, length 552
18:06:24.933100 IP 10.96.128.81.39247 > basement.tftp:  37 RRQ "FX200FTQ2109C2EL.rom" octet tsize 0
18:06:24.934302 IP basement.37528 > 10.96.128.81.39247: UDP, length 516
18:06:24.934705 IP 10.96.128.81 > basement: ICMP 10.96.128.81 udp port 39247 unreachable, length 552
18:06:25.275542 IP 10.96.128.81.9773 > basement.tftp:  37 RRQ "FX200FTQ2109C2EL.rom" octet tsize 0
18:06:25.276742 IP basement.45751 > 10.96.128.81.9773: UDP, length 516
18:06:25.277079 IP 10.96.128.81 > basement: ICMP 10.96.128.81 udp port 9773 unreachable, length 552
18:06:25.290772 IP basement.39876 > oak.fortinet.com.domain: 17298+ [1au] PTR? 81.128.96.10.in-addr.arpa. (54)
18:06:25.300206 IP oak.fortinet.com.domain > basement.39876: 17298 NXDomain* 0/1/1 (112)
18:06:25.300270 IP basement.39876 > oak.fortinet.com.domain: 17298+ PTR? 81.128.96.10.in-addr.arpa. (43)
18:06:25.309278 IP oak.fortinet.com.domain > basement.39876: 17298 NXDomain* 0/1/0 (101)
18:06:25.779433 IP 10.96.128.81.14638 > basement.tftp:  37 RRQ "FX200FTQ2109C2EL.rom" octet tsize 0
18:06:25.780690 IP basement.35264 > 10.96.128.81.14638: UDP, length 516
18:06:25.781101 IP 10.96.128.81 > basement: ICMP 10.96.128.81 udp port 14638 unreachable, length 552
18:06:26.535198 IP 10.96.128.81.45243 > basement.tftp:  37 RRQ "FX200FTQ2109C2EL.rom" octet tsize 0
18:06:26.536514 IP basement.53291 > 10.96.128.81.45243: UDP, length 516
18:06:26.536920 IP 10.96.128.81 > basement: ICMP 10.96.128.81 udp port 45243 unreachable, length 552
18:06:27.674862 IP 10.96.128.81.36671 > basement.tftp:  37 RRQ "FX200FTQ2109C2EL.rom" octet tsize 0
18:06:27.676230 IP basement.60873 > 10.96.128.81.36671: UDP, length 516
18:06:27.676614 IP 10.96.128.81 > basement: ICMP 10.96.128.81 udp port 36671 unreachable, length 552
18:06:29.377169 IP 10.96.128.81.29045 > basement.tftp:  37 RRQ "FX200FTQ2109C2EL.rom" octet tsize 0
18:06:29.378533 IP basement.57606 > 10.96.128.81.29045: UDP, length 516
18:06:29.378909 IP 10.96.128.81 > basement: ICMP 10.96.128.81 udp port 29045 unreachable, length 552
18:06:29.460970 IP basement.47531 > 10.96.128.81.15987: UDP, length 516
18:06:29.461330 IP 10.96.128.81 > basement: ICMP 10.96.128.81 udp port 15987 unreachable, length 552
18:06:29.561398 IP basement.51987 > 10.96.128.81.58208: UDP, length 516
18:06:29.561777 IP 10.96.128.81 > basement: ICMP 10.96.128.81 udp port 58208 unreachable, length 552
18:06:29.712576 IP basement.55350 > 10.96.128.81.35729: UDP, length 516
18:06:29.934407 IP basement.37528 > 10.96.128.81.39247: UDP, length 516
18:06:30.276835 IP basement.45751 > 10.96.128.81.9773: UDP, length 516
18:06:30.780787 IP basement.35264 > 10.96.128.81.14638: UDP, length 516
18:06:30.781347 IP 10.96.128.81 > basement: ICMP 10.96.128.81 udp port 14638 unreachable, length 552
18:06:31.372015 IP 10.96.128.81.50479 > basement.tftp:  37 RRQ "FX200FTQ2109C2EL.rom" octet tsize 0
18:06:31.373353 IP basement.44438 > 10.96.128.81.50479: UDP, length 516
18:06:31.536607 IP basement.53291 > 10.96.128.81.45243: UDP, length 516
18:06:31.537004 IP 10.96.128.81 > basement: ICMP 10.96.128.81 udp port 45243 unreachable, length 552
18:06:32.676350 IP basement.60873 > 10.96.128.81.36671: UDP, length 516
18:06:32.676923 IP 10.96.128.81 > basement: ICMP 10.96.128.81 udp port 36671 unreachable, length 552
18:06:33.376599 IP 10.96.128.81.37969 > basement.tftp:  37 RRQ "FX200FTQ2109C2EL.rom" octet tsize 0
18:06:33.377870 IP basement.34325 > 10.96.128.81.37969: UDP, length 516
18:06:34.378646 IP basement.57606 > 10.96.128.81.29045: UDP, length 516
18:06:34.379157 IP 10.96.128.81 > basement: ICMP 10.96.128.81 udp port 29045 unreachable, length 552
18:06:34.461033 IP basement.47531 > 10.96.128.81.15987: UDP, length 516
18:06:34.461406 IP 10.96.128.81 > basement: ICMP 10.96.128.81 udp port 15987 unreachable, length 552
18:06:34.561478 IP basement.51987 > 10.96.128.81.58208: UDP, length 516
18:06:34.712653 IP basement.55350 > 10.96.128.81.35729: UDP, length 516
18:06:34.934504 IP basement.37528 > 10.96.128.81.39247: UDP, length 516
18:06:35.014468 ARP, Request who-has _gateway tell basement, length 28
18:06:35.014529 ARP, Reply _gateway is-at 02:50:56:56:44:52 (oui Unknown), length 46
18:06:35.276916 IP basement.45751 > 10.96.128.81.9773: UDP, length 516
```

And this curing the 10.31.1.97 tftp session:

```
18:04:50.619282 IP 10.31.1.116.4507 > basement.tftp:  37 RRQ "FX200FTQ2109C2EL.rom" octet tsize 0
18:04:50.620570 IP basement.35535 > 10.31.1.116.4507: UDP, length 516
18:04:50.620751 IP 10.31.1.116 > basement: ICMP 10.31.1.116 udp port 4507 unreachable, length 552
18:04:50.770201 IP 10.31.1.116.4507 > basement.tftp:  37 RRQ "FX200FTQ2109C2EL.rom" octet tsize 0
18:04:50.771532 IP basement.35629 > 10.31.1.116.4507: UDP, length 516
18:04:50.771722 IP 10.31.1.116 > basement: ICMP 10.31.1.116 udp port 4507 unreachable, length 552
18:04:50.991547 IP 10.31.1.116.4507 > basement.tftp:  37 RRQ "FX200FTQ2109C2EL.rom" octet tsize 0
18:04:50.992812 IP basement.59490 > 10.31.1.116.4507: UDP, length 516
18:04:50.993016 IP 10.31.1.116 > basement: ICMP 10.31.1.116 udp port 4507 unreachable, length 552
18:04:51.333577 IP 10.31.1.116.4507 > basement.tftp:  37 RRQ "FX200FTQ2109C2EL.rom" octet tsize 0
18:04:51.334874 IP basement.34005 > 10.31.1.116.4507: UDP, length 516
18:04:51.335059 IP 10.31.1.116 > basement: ICMP 10.31.1.116 udp port 4507 unreachable, length 552
18:04:51.836528 IP 10.31.1.116.4507 > basement.tftp:  37 RRQ "FX200FTQ2109C2EL.rom" octet tsize 0
18:04:51.837824 IP basement.39109 > 10.31.1.116.4507: UDP, length 516
18:04:51.837979 IP 10.31.1.116 > basement: ICMP 10.31.1.116 udp port 4507 unreachable, length 552
18:04:52.590960 IP 10.31.1.116.4507 > basement.tftp:  37 RRQ "FX200FTQ2109C2EL.rom" octet tsize 0
18:04:52.592228 IP basement.46158 > 10.31.1.116.4507: UDP, length 516
18:04:52.592441 IP 10.31.1.116 > basement: ICMP 10.31.1.116 udp port 4507 unreachable, length 552
18:04:53.727449 IP 10.31.1.116.4507 > basement.tftp:  37 RRQ "FX200FTQ2109C2EL.rom" octet tsize 0
18:04:53.728740 IP basement.56210 > 10.31.1.116.4507: UDP, length 516
18:04:53.728924 IP 10.31.1.116 > basement: ICMP 10.31.1.116 udp port 4507 unreachable, length 552
18:04:55.437455 IP 10.31.1.116.4507 > basement.tftp:  37 RRQ "FX200FTQ2109C2EL.rom" octet tsize 0
18:04:55.438751 IP basement.33467 > 10.31.1.116.4507: UDP, length 516
18:04:55.438980 IP 10.31.1.116 > basement: ICMP 10.31.1.116 udp port 4507 unreachable, length 552
18:04:55.520253 IP basement.55033 > 10.31.1.116.4507: UDP, length 516
18:04:55.520420 IP 10.31.1.116 > basement: ICMP 10.31.1.116 udp port 4507 unreachable, length 552
18:04:55.620629 IP basement.35535 > 10.31.1.116.4507: UDP, length 516
18:04:55.620843 IP 10.31.1.116 > basement: ICMP 10.31.1.116 udp port 4507 unreachable, length 552
18:04:55.686462 ARP, Request who-has 10.31.1.116 tell basement, length 28
18:04:55.686681 ARP, Reply 10.31.1.116 is-at fa:16:53:2d:76:99 (oui Unknown), length 46
18:04:55.695870 ARP, Request who-has basement tell 10.31.1.116, length 46
18:04:55.695875 ARP, Reply basement is-at fa:16:53:6e:cf:9d (oui Unknown), length 28
18:04:55.771612 IP basement.35629 > 10.31.1.116.4507: UDP, length 516
18:04:55.992903 IP basement.59490 > 10.31.1.116.4507: UDP, length 516
18:04:56.334979 IP basement.34005 > 10.31.1.116.4507: UDP, length 516
18:04:56.837928 IP basement.39109 > 10.31.1.116.4507: UDP, length 516
18:04:56.838158 IP 10.31.1.116 > basement: ICMP 10.31.1.116 udp port 4507 unreachable, length 552
```

Does anyone know what is going on ?

Thanks in advance for any tips !

Jack

Comment: Seems like your ports are closed, you might want to ssh in to the connecting server and try using netcat to see if the ports are open on the destination server. i'm not familiar with tftp specifically but there is likely a way to open ports.

Comment: TFTP is using UDP port 69. I think it is open and I was able to tftp files from "US-237" level.  my X-1 device is running above "US-237" level, and tftp timeout  at that level.  It seems the request recaches the "Basement" server, but never return back.